# How to install third party modules (Mu)?

Tags: python-3.x, mu

I'm trying (again) to learn Python. I'm just gonna go through Automate the Boring Stuff and I'm using Mu. I'm stuck trying to install third-party modules.

The book says to use the Windows Command Prompt, change the directory to wherever the pip tool is and then install it.

My confusion stems from where to locate the right folder. It says "Then run cd pip folder, where pip’s folder is C:\Users<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts on Windows"

Under AppData\Local, I have a Programs folder, but there's no Python in there. In AppData\Local, there's a "python" folder which contains only some logs from Mu. I also have a "pip" folder.

So I tried installing pyperclip using different directories:

[image]

But when I run code like this:

```
import pyperclip

text1 = 'Hello'
pyperclip.copy(text1)
text2 = pyperclip.paste()
print(text2)
```

It gives me the ModuleNotFoundError message.

I searched for the pip.exe and got these results:

[image]

Clicked on every one, but either nothing happens or, when opening the ones located in AppData, it opens up a command prompt for a second, but it closes itself immediately (and then creates these files).

Comment: You shouldn't have that many pip.exe to begin with. If you install the module and it doesn't show up then your editor is using a different interpreter version, because of the amount you have.

Comment: @BoobyTrap What would you suggest I do? Should I just uninstall everything Python and reinstall what I need and see if the problem persists?

Comment: If you don't have any other use for python then I would suggest that, or at least clearing the anaconda interpreters. According to what I saw, you could also install mu using pip in your cmd and it should work fine then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than what I said in the comments, in regards to removing all the pips.
I suggest doing the following in your cmd:
`pip install mu-editor`

This will install mu-editor using your default pip. After that type in `pip install pyperclip`.
This will install that module.

Once you are done, just type in `mu-editor` in the cmd and it will run the mu-editor with your interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and here's the solution using Mu 1.1.1:

1. At the bottom right, click the cog icon [cog icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojbi7.png)
2. Click the 'Third Party Packages" tab
3. Type in 'pyperclip' then click OK